# Creating a controller / action href

Tags: grails, tags, hyperlink, href

While Grails has several tags to generate either resource links or anchor tags, what about a plain href? Say I'm coding some AJAX functions on my own and I want to say something like

```
$.post("<g:href controller='mycontroller' action='update' />');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [createLink](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.3/ref/Tags/createLink.html) is what you're looking for:

```
<a href="${createLink(controller:'mycontroller', action:'update')}" />
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.